# I am using python for some matrix related program how can I display it in the form of a matrix. (The ends match indentation regardless of digits)

Tags: python, matrix

I am using python for some matrix related program how can I display it in the form of a matrix. (The ends match indentation regardless of digits) like it should not be:

```
[1,304,67]
[387,378,2]
[6783,2,2222]

#it should be:
[1,  304, 67]
[387, 378, 2]
[6783,2,2222]
```

I have tried to come up with some solutions to calculate and add extra space after commas but they do not work properly

Comment: This is not a matrix, it is a List of Lists. Although you can modify the way the data is displayed to suit your needs, the data is not accessed using rows and columns.,

Answer (score 0):

My algorithm would be:

1. Iterate the rows ans values, get max value per column
2. Convert max value to string und get str length.
3. Iterate again to output, convert the values to strings, output the string, place coma, add (max value of column Str length)-(current str length) spaces.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to do the trick:

```
data = [
    [1, 304, 67],
    [387, 378, 2],
    [6783, 2, 2222],
]

rows = [",".join(str(i) for i in row) for row in data]
max_len = max(len(row) for row in rows)
for row in rows:
    while (space_needed := max_len - len(row)) > 0:
        row = row.replace(",", ", ", space_needed)
    print(row)
```

The output is

```
1,  304, 67
387, 378, 2
6783,2,2222
```

– feel free to add the brackets at your leisure.